# Nginx Frontend, Apache Backend, Too Many Time Wait Connections

Tags: nginx

I am using Apache as a backend with suPHP and mod_sec and nginx as a frontend proxy.

This works well so far, but for some reason Apache suddenly spawns so many processes that the CPU load goes up a lot. I have already reduced worker_connections and all timeouts suspecting someone is hammering the server too much e.g. a bot or so but the problem persists.

I checked the Time_Wait connections when the CPU load goes up and at one point I had like 5000 TIME_WAIT. The CPU load was going through the roof.

Any ideas what else I can do other than:

`echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_reuse`

Update: tw_reuse helps a little but I have to analyze it for a bit. Is there anything else I can try to get more information?

Answer (score 0):

Analyze nginx access logs first!

If lot of requests from your real users, you need configuring or upgrade your server.

If that is bots or bad parsers, you need block them and tune you system params.

Do not change any sysctl params before not found problem.